# how do i know if i want to know last modified date folder name in vba

Tags: vba, directory, subdirectory, last-modified, fso

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set froot = fso.GetFolder(strstartfldr)

For Each fldr In froot.SubFolders
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem fldr.DateCreated
Next
```

at this program i can get the subfolder list in combbobox1
but from this subfolder how can i know which is last modified folder name
I'm sure there is simple code but cant figure out

anyone help

Answer (score 0):

### Last Folder (FSO)

- The following function gets the name of the folder that was last created.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function LastFolder(FolderPath As String) As String
    
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim froot As Object
    Dim fldr As Object
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set froot = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fDC As Date
    Dim TMP As Date
    For Each fldr In froot.subfolders
        TMP = fldr.DateCreated
        If TMP > fDC Then
            fDC = TMP
            fName = fldr.Name
        End If
    Next fldr
    
    LastFolder = fName

End Function

Sub testLastFolder()
    Debug.Print LastFolder("F:\StackOverFlow")
End Sub
```